# Como trabalhar com Arrays no Angular com impressão em tela?

Tags: angular

Ainda conheço pouco de Angular e conheço somente o básico, observem o trecho de código:

```
 listarTodas(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cidadesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => console.log(response.json()));
  }
```

veja como está a saida!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Eu gostaria de saber como somente imprimir os valores do atributo
  **codigoEstado**.
- Eu gostaria também saber como somente imprimir valores que o
  **codigoEstado** seja igual a **1**.

Só estou pedindo ajuda aqui porque eu já fiz várias tentativas sem sucesso, já procurei na documentação do Angular na internet em blogs e fóruns e não encontrei, preciso muito de ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [`*ngForOf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) para imprimir os atributos:

```
<!-- Assumindo que o seu controlador tem uma variavel `cidades` onde guarda o resultado da sua promessa -->
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cidade of cidades">
        <span>{{cidade.nome}} => {{cidade.codigoEstado}}</span> 
        <!-- resultados -->
        <!-- Rio Branco => 1 -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- Santos => 6 -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

A directiva `*ngFor` vai percorrer o seu *array* e imprimir todos os elementos que estejam contidos nele. Caso adicione ou remova elementos desse *array*, o `DOM` será actualizado automaticamente.

Para imprimir somente os elementos cujo `codigoEstado === 1`, pode usar o [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cidade of cidades">
        <span *ngIf="cidade.codigoEstado === 1">{{cidade.nome}} => {{cidade.codigoEstado}}</span> 
        <!-- resultados -->
        <!-- Rio Branco => 1 -->
        <!-- Cruzeiro Sul => 1 -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Tal como o nome indica, a directiva `*ngIf` permite controlar que elementos são escritos no DOM. Caso a condição da directiva seja verdadeira, o elemento pai é escrito no DOM. Caso seja falso, é removido do DOM.